# why I can't start a docker container ? it reports something about the port being allocated

Tags: linux, docker, networking, port, lsof

[image: Terminal screenshot]

use lsof to show a port, but every port return same info...

```
[kfadmin@master fundrisksys]$ lsof -i:136
24223   /usr/bin/bash   /dev/pts/0
24223   /usr/bin/bash   /dev/pts/0
24223   /usr/bin/bash   /dev/pts/0
24223   /usr/bin/bash   /dev/pts/0

[kfadmin@master fundrisksys]$ lsof -i:7895
24223   /usr/bin/bash   /dev/pts/0
24223   /usr/bin/bash   /dev/pts/0
24223   /usr/bin/bash   /dev/pts/0
24223   /usr/bin/bash   /dev/pts/0
```

I can't use any port, it shows same info:
Bind for 0.0.0.0:8001 failed: port is already allocated

I try to kill the pid, but the terminal will be killed

Comment: Please [don't show images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please explain why this question is tagged with C++

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to run a `docker ps -a`?
You may have a stopped container that reserved this port.

Answer (score 1):

Use `netstat -tulpn` or `ss -tulpn` and look at used ports. Find app and pid that uses this port.